# Calculate value from two field and show in third field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textfield

How  can we take value from two text fields and after performing some action, how to show the result in third text field in JavaScript????

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: Please attach your code to this question, so reviewers can reply to your code.
A good question almost should have some example code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <!-- input text boxes -->
  <input type="text" name="input-1">
  <input type="text" name="input-2">
  <input type="text" name="input-3">

  <!-- button to run calculation -->
  <button id="btn">Calculate</button>

  <!-- include jquery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    // put in this function because you want to wait until the page loads
    $(function() {

      $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {

        // grab input from input 1 and input 2
        var val1 = $('input[value="input-1"]').val();
        var val2 = $('input[value="input-2"]').val();

        // we are just appending the values together to get val3 but you can do whatever you want for this part. I am just using this as an example.
        var val3 = val1 + ' ' + val2;

        // set value to input 3
        $('input[value="input-3"]').val(val3);
      });

    });

  </script>

</html>
```